# Yii2 dropDownList mark option selected

Tags: drop-down-menu, selected, yii2

Hi i'm trying to make a drop down list with selected value but there is still no progress, drop down is rendenering but always first option is selected.

```
$company_id = (int) $params['company_id'];
$options = [
    'options' => [
         $company_id => [
            'selected' => 'selected',
            'label' => 'test'
        ]
     ]
];
echo $form->field($model, 'company_id')->dropDownList($companies_list, $options);
```

whats wrong with that code? I edited my code and i set 'label' => 'test' in my option, and this works, but selected still not

Ok solution found, in framework code i found in renderSelectionOptions method :

```
$attrs = isset($options[$key]) ? $options[$key] : [];
$attrs['value'] = (string) $key;
$attrs['selected'] = $selection !== null &&
    (!is_array($selection) && !strcmp($key, $selection)
    || is_array($selection) && in_array($key, $selection));
```

so all what i need to do is :

```
$model->company_id = $company_id;
```

before rendering section

Comment: As a suggestion, if you already answered your question, please write it as an answer and accept it(That would be more comfortable for other people to find answer).

Comment: @szapio am also facing the same problem, can you explain how to do this for dependent dropdown please see problem link below [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473465/dependent-dropdown-in-yii2-making-values-reset-while-updating-the-active-form)

Comment: @szapio can you say where i can use these both codes $model->company_id = $company_id; and $attrs = isset($options[$key]) ? $options[$key] : [];
$attrs['value'] = (string) $key;
$attrs['selected'] = $selection !== null &&
    (!is_array($selection) && !strcmp($key, $selection)
    || is_array($selection) && in_array($key, $selection)); because am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a note for future visitors:

If you are using `ActiveForm` then value of your model field will be used as the selected value but if you are not using `ActiveForm` and generating dropdown list with `Html` helper then `dropDownList` function accepts another parameter `selection` as well, in which you can pass the value that you want to make selected, as mentioned in [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 40; $x++) {
       if ($x=="1"){
            $items[$x] = $x." week";
        }else{
            $items[$x] = $x." weeks";
        }
    }
$weeks=28;
<?= Html::dropDownList('s_id', $selection = $weeks, $items, ['prompt' => '--Choose Week--','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
```