# Yii 2 dropDownList - Default value not being selected

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii 2 ActiveForm, trying to make option 7 "default".

To do this, I have to use the options array, but when I do so, my html attribute "selected" is not being rendered at all when viewing the HTML source. I get no errors.

If I use other options, such as "label" it works as intended.

```
$form->field($model, 'date')->dropDownList($months, [
'options'=>array(
'7' => ['label' => 'JULY', 'selected'=>true],
),
]);
```

According to the docs, any "valid" option is accepted, I assume "selected" is valid as it's a HTML dropdown list?

This is what is generated:

```
<select id="log-date" class="form-control" name="Log[date]">
<option value="1">JANUARY</option>
<option value="2">FEBRUARY</option>
<option value="3">MARCH</option>
<option value="4">APRIL</option>
<option value="5">MAY</option>
<option value="6">JUNE</option>
<option value="7" label="label works fine">JULY</option>
<option value="8">AUGUST</option>
<option value="9">SEPTEMBER</option>
<option value="10">OCTOBER</option>
<option value="11">NOVEMBER</option>
<option value="12">DECEMBER</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does `'selected'=>'selected'` not work?

Comment: No it does not do anything. The HTML doesn't change at all actually. Maybe it's a bug. Thank you for trying. My workaround for this is to dynamically change the array of months (current month will be loaded first in the array)

Comment: Refer http://www.saidur-rahman.com/default-selected-value-in-a-dropdownlist-in-yii/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It was answered here: [Yii2 dropDownList mark option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108609/yii2-dropdownlist-mark-option-selected#). You need to set the date attribute:

   ```
   $model->date = 7;
   $form->field($model, 'date')->dropDownList($months);
   ```
2. There is also discussion from developers: [dropDownList pre Selection not rendering 'selected'](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2728)
   They propose that you either define default value for attribute in init() method or set it directly in view (this is same as answer above). I also do it like this

   ```
   $model->priority = $model->isNewRecord ? 2 : $model->priority;
   $form->field($model, 'priority',[
          'options'=>['class'=>'col-xs-12 col-md-3']
       ])->dropDownList($priorityList)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the code for yii2 is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList($order_statuses, ['value' => !empty($model->status) ? $model->status : 1]); ?>
```

where 1 is id for default selected value.