# Dependent Dropdown in Yii2 making values reset while updating the Active form

Tags: yii2

Here my problem is i have a form . In that i have dependent dropdown.
for example if i select company name it automatically selects the dependent company email and company phone number. This is working perfectly while creating. but the problem is while am updating the same form, the dependent value getting reset. so that makes me to select the company name for every time but i don't to be like that. once if i select the value while creating the value shouldn't change while updating also.

```
_form.php

<?= $form->field($model, 'employee_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()->all(),'id','employeecode'),
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Select a employeecode ...',
                'onchange' => '
                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employeedetails/lists2&id='.'"+$(this).val().split("-")[0], function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#claimprocess-claim_for" ).html( data );
                                    }),

                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employeedetails/lists3&id='.'"+$(this).val().split("-")[0], function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#claimprocess-email" ).html( data );
                                    }),

                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employeedetails/lists1&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#claimprocess-employee_name" ).html( data );
                                    });',
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

This is Controller code
    controller.php

```
public function actionLists($id)
    {
        $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['company_id' => $id])
                ->count();

        $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['company_id' => $id])
                ->all();

        if($countEmployeedetails>0){
            foreach($employeedetails as $employee){
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->employeecode."</option>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }

    public function actionLists1($id)
    {
        $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->count();


        $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->all();

        if($countEmployeedetails >= 0)
        {
            foreach($employeedetails as $employee)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->name."</option>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }

    public function actionLists2($id)
    {

        $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->count();


        $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->all();

        if($countEmployeedetails >= 0)
        {
            foreach($employeedetails as $employee)
            {
                // $arr["id"] . '-' . $arr['designation']
                    echo "<option value='".$employee->id. '-' .$employee->name. "'>".$employee->RelationName."</option>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you storing both the value of the company ID and the dependent value? or just one of them?

Comment: both company_id and dependent values. while updating company_id is displaying the selected value, but only the dependent values alone getting reset

Comment: You should move the entire update in a js function and call it when you update a page. In this way it will get executed and the details will be brought over on edit.

Comment: pls give me sample code

Comment: considering you do not accept answers ever... no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer, actually mistake was mine, because here am using getting records based on company_id but here i have used approvaldetails table id so that is the  mistake, after i changed it to company_id, now its working good

```
public function actionLists2($id)
    {

        $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['company_id' => $id])
                ->count();


        $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
                ->where(['company_id' => $id])
                ->all();

        if($countEmployeedetails >= 0)
        {
            foreach($employeedetails as $employee)
            {
                // $arr["id"] . '-' . $arr['designation']
                    echo "<option value='".$employee->id. '-' .$employee->name. "'>".$employee->RelationName."</option>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: you dont need to query twice the same `sql`, you can use `count($employeeDetails)` to get the total number of records and remove the first query on the top the gets `$countEmployeedetails`