# Dependent Dropdown in Yii2 lost values on Update

Tags: yii2

I created a form with a dropdownlist dependent on another (without extensions) and it ran fast.

But when you try to change the same form, the value of the second drop-down list is lost (`type_id`). Basically the **Type** field depends on the selected **Area**. See my code:

**_form.php**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'area_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Department::find()->where(['helpdesk' => 1])->all(),'id','name'),['prompt'=>'Selecione a Área',
        'onchange' => '
        $.post("index.php?r=helpdesk/solicitation/lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(),function(data){
            $("select#solicitation-type_id").html(data);
        });']) ?>  

<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(['prompt'=>'Selecione a Área']);
?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionLists($id)
{
    $countType = Type::find()
            ->where(['area_id' => $id])
            ->count();

    $types = Type::find()
            ->where(['area_id' => $id])
            ->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();

    if($countType > 0 )
    {
        foreach($types as $type ){
            echo "<option value='".$type->id."'>".$type->name."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option> - </option>";
    }

}
```

I think it's the same problem at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473465/dependent-dropdown-in-yii2-making-values-reset-while-updating-the-active-form), but I did not understand how it worked.

Comment: you mean the depdrop down does not pick the saved value? when you try to edit the record.

Comment: yes! its lost the field value  (type_id)

Comment: how are your loading the value to the model are you using `findOne()` to select the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide the default set of options from which it should select the saved option whereas you are not providing any data

```
<?php
$types = Type::find()
            ->where(['area_id' => $model->area_id])
            ->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();

echo $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($types,'id','name'),['prompt'=>'Selecione a Área']);
?>
```

Now when you will use `findOne()` and select the model the saved value for the `type_id` will be automatically selected.

*You can move the above query in the `controller/action` and pass the `$types` to the view.*

also you can make you method `actionLists` D.R.Y by using `count($types)` and remove the first query

```
public function actionLists($id)
{

    $types = Type::find()
            ->where(['area_id' => $id])
            ->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();

    if(count($types) > 0 )
    {
        foreach($types as $type ){
            echo "<option value='".$type->id."'>".$type->name."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option> - </option>";
    }

}
```